# How do you find the number of primes in a sequence up to the first thousand terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

I have a sequence:

$ 7,19,61,193,577,1633,4417, ... $

and I'd like to find out how many primes and semiprimes there are in this sequence up to the first thousand terms? Any idea how I could do that quickly?

To form the sequence I did: $ 3(2)+1, 6(3)+1, 12(5)+1, 24(8)+1, 48(12)+1, 96(17)+1, ... $

i.e. : $ 3+3+1, 6+6+6+1, 12+12+12+12+12+1, ... $

Comment: Well I took 3,3,1 and then 6,6,6,1, and then 12,12,12,12,12,1 etc. so the 2,3,5,12,17 are the number of times you multiply the 3, 6, 12, etc.

Comment: If $t_n$ is the $n$th triangular number, then a formula for the sequence is $a_n = 3\cdot 2^{n-1}(2+t_{n-1})+1$ and we know that $t_n = n(n+1)/2.$

Comment: So this is a triangular sequence you're saying?

Comment: No.  The triangular numbers come into the formula.  If you simplify my calculations you get $a_n = 3\cdot 2^{n-2}(n^2-n+4) +1.$  It's easy to write a quick loop in Maple and get the list that Robert gets below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $24$ primes in the first $1000$ terms, namely terms number
$$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 21, 23, 24, 27, 46, 47, 48, 50, 54, 65, 68, 101, 159, 286, 483, 572, 802, 873$$

There's no shortcut, just generate the terms and test for primality.
Fortunately, that's quite fast.  In Maple on my computer it took less than half a second.

Counting the semiprimes would be harder, I think, because I don't know of a way to test for semiprimes that's much faster than factoring, and the $1000$'th term has $307$ digits - no picnic to factor.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand this

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: What are the numbers you listed?

Comment: Oh are those the terms in the sequence that yield primes?

Comment: If $a_n$ is the $n$'th number in your sequence, I'm saying that $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_{12}, \ldots, a_{873}$ are prime.

Comment: that's incredible how it starts off so strong and only gives 24/1000 primes

Comment: @geocalc33 The primes thin out and the terms in the sequence grow exponentially.

Comment: No members of your sequence are divisible by $2$ or $3$.  For small numbers, not being divisible by $2$ or $3$ gives you a good chance of being prime.  For large numbers, not so much.

Comment: Ah I see that it's the law of small numbers taking effect here